# The type or namespace name 'EventReceivers' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint Provider Hosted app developed with Visual Studio (MVC 5, C#) 2015 and hosted in SharePoint 2013. Recently, I have upgraded Visual Studio to 2017.

I have the below namespaces on TokenHelper.cs class, but get error "The type or namespace name 'EventReceivers' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

It would be a great help if someone can help resolving it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow install instructions here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038&force_isolation=true

Comment: The issue is resolved. Installed SP Client Component SDK. Thanks